# Java EnumSet Syntax Assistance

Tags: java, enums, enumset

I am just starting to learn Java and I'm working through a simple application that works with a deck of cards. Currently, I'm trying to instantiate a Suit class with an enum. I wanted to use the EnumSet functionality, but I'm really having trouble wrapping my head around what is going on here.

I have looked through several examples and I believe I'm just not fully comprehending the syntax.

Here's what I have so far. What I want to end up with is an EnumSet with the values of each `Suit` of Cards (clubs, diamonds, hearts, spades).

```
public class Suits {

    public enum Suit {
        CLUBS("Clubs"),
        DIAMONDS("Diamonds"),
        HEARTS("Hearts"),
        SPADES("Spades");
        private String displayText;


        Suit(String displayText) { 
            this.displayText = displayText;
        } 

        public String getDisplayText() {
            return this.displayText;
        }

    }

    final EnumSet<Suit> allSuits = EnumSet.allof(Suit.values());

}
```

I know that the syntax on the `final EnumSet` is wrong. I'm just not sure what exactly I am doing wrong. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should pass a `Class<Suit>` instance instead of a `Suit[]`:

```
final EnumSet<Suit> allSuits = EnumSet.allOf(Suit.class);
```

The method signature is [`allOf(Class<E> elementType)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html#allOf-java.lang.Class-).